# Attribute change not being detected

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local cost = 100
local MoneyInv = 0
local PlayerService = game:GetService("Players")

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(player)

    if player.Parent.Parent == game.Workspace then
        name = player.Parent.Name
    else
        name = player.Parent.Parent.Name
    end

    if script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Owner ~= 0 then
        RealPlayer = PlayerService:GetPlayerByUserId(script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Owner.Value)
        print("abc")
        print(RealPlayer:GetAttributes())

        if RealPlayer.Name == name and MoneyInv >= cost then
            RealPlayer:SetAttribute("MoneyInv", -cost)
            print("abc")
            local MoneyMachine = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.MoneyMachines.MoneyMachine
            MoneyMachine.CanCollide = true
            MoneyMachine.Transparency = 
                        MoneyMachine.CanTouch = true
            MoneyMachine.Script.Enabled = true
            script.Parent:Destroy()
        end
    end
end)
```

Every player has an attribute called `MoneyInv` but this script does not detect that value being changed, it always says 0. I don't know how to update the value.

I expected it to update on its own but it didn't.

```
if script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Owner ~= 0 then
    RealPlayer = PlayerService:GetPlayerByUserId(script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Owner.Value)
    print("abc")
    print(RealPlayer:GetAttributes())
```

When I call `GetAttributes` it says that `MoneyInv` is 0 even it shouldn't be